# How to Automated copy from local file to website and save to local file

Tags: java, json, selenium, automation, rest-assured

I have a lot of json files waiting to be converted json schemas. So I just want to write my files in json format and then automatically converted and save. In short this auyomation will copy json file and will paste to the example.com website and than save the response on my local file

Here is my steps :

I want to copy a content written in notepad on my desktop and paste it into a website. How can I do that ? I it possible with selenium ?

Steps :

1. Copy inside C:\Users\mc\Desktop\usages.json
2. Go to example.com (this is an example site)
3. I will paste the content I copied after I find the correct
   elements(xpath or css selector)
4. In this website have copy button so i will click this button
5. And i will save the copied content into my local new text file like
   usagescopy.json

Comment: There are some `CLI` applications that you can run on your local computer. So you may not need all of this.

Comment: @Eldar Yes but while doing this I want to improve my knowledge of both selenium and bash script or automation